# SwipeRefreshLayout Circle is lagging during refresh

Tags: java, android, java-threads, swiperefreshlayout, android-thread

In onResume I set and update my recylclerview adapter in a thread. Before setting or updating I do swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true) and after this swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false). But the circle of the SwipeRefreshLayout is lagging or isn't even visible.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(first) {
                    adapter= new Adapter(MainActivity.this, list1, list2, list3, true);

                }else{
                    adapter.update(list1, list2, list3);
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(first){
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            first = false;
                        }else {
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: it takes a very very short time update and set an adapter .. that your visible eyes can see the difference.. so the loader isnt visible ! to test it you can run a handler and **delay the loading**

Comment: But if I don't use a Thread it takes about 2 seconds to load. I have some images in Recyclerview and the circle is visible laggy

Comment: what's the point of nesting two `Runnable` - or even using a `Runnable` - or even trying to set a new adapter `onResume()`? this all appears abusive to me, so it probably is no wonder that it lags.

Comment: I have a recyclerview that needs too long to load. So the activity starts only after a few Seconds. That's the reason why I set and update the Adapter in a Thread in onResume. (It should also update every time the user returns to the app)